# How to call a piecewise monotone function?

Tags: reference-request

I would like to know if there is a standard way to call a piecewise monotone function with the following property: if one of the branches is increasing then all other branches are increasing, and if one of the branches is decreasing then all other branches are decreasing.

Comment: I don’t get it. Is “branch” a monotone subdomain (piece) of the piecewise monotone function? Then your condition simply says that the function as a whole is monotone, doesn’t it?

Comment: The domain of the function is subdivided into maximal intervals where the function is monotone. It is required, that in each maximal interval the function is monotone, i.e., is piecewise monotone function. The additional property is: if increasing in one maximal interval, then it is increasing for all the maximal intervals, the analogous to decreasing.
There are functions with discontinuities with this property that are not monotone as a whole.

Comment: My suggestion is that these are the "sawtooth" functions.

Comment: I see, it is not required to be monotone at the endpoints of the pieces. That makes sense.

Comment: So an example is the function $\tan(x)$ ?

Comment: Yes, $\tan(x)$ is a good example. 

Comment: Perhaps the term "sawtooth" is too restricted. For by definition it is sawtooth due to its resemblance to the teeth on the edge of a saw. The common use is that a sawtooth wave goes upward and then sharply drops (not necessarily the case).


Comment: Piecewise nondecreasing/nonincreasing?

Comment: ...or something ending with "-tropism" (always growing towards infinity/-infinity)

Comment: How about the "fractional part" function $f(x) = x-\lfloor x \rfloor$.  Another example?

Comment: Yes, is another example.

Comment: Why not piecewise monotone? anyway you will have to define it...

Comment: I still think they are sawtooth functions. There are fine saws and rough saws, for different purposes, and many saws have teeth of different shapes, although typically they all face the same direction, conforming with your requirement. If you choose the intervals of monotonicity for your function to be maximal, then your functions will have sharp jump disontinuities at the boundaries of the intervals, just like a saw. (The alternative of piecewise monotone doesn't seem to carry the connotation that each piece is monotone in the same way.)